# How to access ReactiveSecurityContextHolder from ExceptionResolver?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I understand that in order to keep the context, the reactive chain of methods must not be broken.  However, I need to get access to the context from the ExceptionResolver (after an exception has been thrown.)

My exception resolver is extending `AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler` and when I try to get the context via `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()` it returns empty.  Obviously because the reactive chain has been broken.

How can I get access to the authentication object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the authentication object by overriding the `handle` method:

```java
public class TestHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    public TestHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, ResourceProperties resourceProperties,
                       ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super(errorAttributes, resourceProperties, applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable throwable) {
        Mono<Principal> authObject = exchange.getPrincipal();
        //Handle exception here
        return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    }
}
```

Another approach is to implement the `ErrorWebExceptionHandler` directly:

```java
public class TestHandler implements ErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, Throwable throwable) {
        Mono<Principal> authObject = serverWebExchange.getPrincipal();
        //Handle exception here
        return serverWebExchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    }
}
```